# Lower central series of a free group 3

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Let $F$ be free group on two generator $x$ and $y$ and  $F_i$ be $i$-th component of lower central series of $F$. If $F$ is generated mod $F_1=[F,F]$ by $b_1,...,b_n$  then $F_r$ is generated mod $F_{r+1}$ by elements of the form
$[b_i,w]$ with $w \in F_{r-1}$.
Where could I find the proof of the above statement?

Comment: It's not hard to prove. It follows from the fact that $F_r = [F,F_{r-1}]$ and the commutator map $F \times F_{r-1} \to F_r/F_{r+1}$ defined by $(f,w) \mapsto [f,w]F_{r+1}$ is bilinear. You can restrict the elements $w$ to elements of a generating set of $F_{r-1}$ mod $F_r$ if you want to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if I have a $c\in F_r$ how could I find algorithmically  $w_1,...,w_n\in F_{r-1}$ and $d\in F_{r+1}$ such that   $c=[b_1,w_1]...[b_n,w_n] d$